# QGIS Azimuthal Orthographic Projection with Raster

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system

I want to use QGIS to make a world map that has two or three azimuthal orthographic maps.  I would also like to use [Natural Earth's Cross-blended Hypsometric Tints](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-raster-data/50m-cross-blend-hypso).  Is this possible? The example was done using ArcGIS Pro.  I would like to use QGIS if possible.

[image: ArcGIS Pro Example]

Comment: What have you tried? Here's a partial proj.4 string for an orthographic projcrs: +proj=ortho +datum=WGS84 +lat_0=15.0 +lon_0=-80.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +units=m no_defs

Comment: I have tried this: +proj=ortho +lat_0=15 +lon_0=-88 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs.  Nothing displays when I use this string on a raster. Works on vector data.

Comment: I don't have much experience with QGIS.  Trying to familiarize myself with it.  I'm also new to custom CRS.

Comment: It may be a rendering issue.  I tried the proj from my comment above again and noticed the the raster will display at certain zoom levels and extents.  but as I zoom or pan the image will disappear. However, it will reappear when I go back to the previous extent.

Comment: Here is an error message: 2017-09-01T20:29:56 1 Could not reproject view extent: forward transform of
   (0.000000, 0.000000)
   PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=ortho +lat_0=-36 +lon_0=175 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371000 +b=6371000 +units=m +no_defs
   Error: tolerance condition error

Comment: You might be better off if you define the source CRS on the same sphere. You won't see a difference on a global scale.